# ggplot2: Splitting 1 level of grouping variable into multiple geom items within aes()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a plot that works for me, but need some help putting all the `geom_line`(s) and `ribbon`(s) in the same legend, like the image of the legend below (done in Excel). As I understand it, ggplot puts items in a legend using the aes() function and the color/fill commands, but each row of data needs a unique grouping variable. I think my resultant plot would be asking ggplot to try and split the same group level into two different aesthetics (making 4 lines from 2 grouping levels?). I'm not sure how to create this though without restructuring the data and loosing what I made so far. Essentially, I'm trying to group my "q2" column by the "group" variable (High/Low) like my geom_ribbon, but with their own lines and colors (called "Median (High Years)" and "Median (Low Years)"). Additionally, I hope to add the secondary dataframe ("blackline") it to the legend as well.

**My goal:**

[image]

**Attempt:**

[image]

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)  

ggplot(ribbons2, aes(x=Month, fill=group)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=q1,ymax=q3), alpha=0.4) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=Month, y=q2, fill =group, color = c("#DC143C", "#556B2F")), linewidth = 0.4, linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_line(data=blackline, mapping=aes(x=Month, y=q2, fill = group), inherit.aes = FALSE, linewidth = 0.8) + 
  facet_wrap(factor(Zone)~ ., labeller=as_labeller(c("West" = "West", 
                                                     "Whipray" = "Whipray", 
                                                     "Rankin" = "Rankin", 
                                                     "Crocodile" = "Crocodile Dragover*")), 
             scales='free') + 
  
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(5,6,7,8,9,10,11)) +
  
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), 
                     limits=c(0, 1), 
                     breaks=c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0)) +
  
  scale_fill_manual(name="", labels=c('25th - 75th percentile (High years)',
                                      '25th - 75th percentile (Low years)'),
                                      values=c("#d8e4bc", "#e8bcbc")) +
  
  theme_classic()+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"), 
        legend.justification = "top", 
        strip.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 7)) + 
  ylab("Frequency of Occurence")
```

Error:

```
Error in `geom_line()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (55)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `colour`
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: In geom_line(aes(x = Month, y = q2, fill = group, color = c("#DC143C",  :
  Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
2: In geom_line(data = blackline, mapping = aes(x = Month, y = q2,  :
  Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
```

Data (2 data.frames):

```
> dput(blackline)
structure(list(Zone = c("Crocodile", "Crocodile", "Crocodile", 
"Crocodile", "Crocodile", "Crocodile", "Crocodile", "Rankin", 
"Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "Whipray", "Whipray", 
"Whipray", "Whipray", "Whipray", "Whipray", "Whipray"), Month = c(5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), q2 = c(`50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, 
`50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0.0909, 
`50%` = 0.1818, `50%` = 0.1364, `50%` = 0.0909, `50%` = 0.2727, 
`50%` = 0.1818, `50%` = 0.05, `50%` = 0.1, `50%` = 0.2, `50%` = 0.25, 
`50%` = 0.05, `50%` = 0.1, `50%` = 0.05, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, 
`50%` = 0, `50%` = 0.1053, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0), 
    group = c("2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
    "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
    "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
    "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021")), row.names = c(NA, 
-28L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
    Zone = c("Crocodile", "Rankin", "West", "Whipray"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:7, 8:14, 15:21, 22:28), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE))


> dput(ribbons)
structure(list(Zone = c("Crocodile", "Crocodile", "Crocodile", 
"Crocodile", "Crocodile", "Crocodile", "Crocodile", "Rankin", 
"Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "Whipray", "Whipray", 
"Whipray", "Whipray", "Whipray", "Whipray", "Whipray", "Crocodile", 
"Crocodile", "Crocodile", "Crocodile", "Crocodile", "Crocodile", 
"Crocodile", "Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin", 
"Rankin", "Rankin", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"Whipray", "Whipray", "Whipray", "Whipray", "Whipray", "Whipray", 
"Whipray"), Month = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11), q1 = c(`25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0.05, `25%` = 0, 
`25%` = 0.1, `25%` = 0.0625, `25%` = 0.0125, `25%` = 0.0909, 
`25%` = 0.086, `25%` = 0.0649, `25%` = 0.2273, `25%` = 0.2208, 
`25%` = 0.4302, `25%` = 0.2727, `25%` = 0.05, `25%` = 0.2, `25%` = 0.25, 
`25%` = 0.25, `25%` = 0.3636, `25%` = 0.25, `25%` = 0.15, `25%` = 0.0132, 
`25%` = 0, `25%` = 0.0789, `25%` = 0.1096, `25%` = 0.2763, `25%` = 0.2868, 
`25%` = 0.0395, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, 
`25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, 
`25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0.05, 
`25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, 
`25%` = 0, `25%` = 0, `25%` = 0.0132, `25%` = 0), q2 = c(`50%` = 0, 
`50%` = 0, `50%` = 0.05, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0.1, `50%` = 0.1, 
`50%` = 0.075, `50%` = 0.1364, `50%` = 0.1136, `50%` = 0.1357, 
`50%` = 0.2273, `50%` = 0.2273, `50%` = 0.4773, `50%` = 0.2792, 
`50%` = 0.075, `50%` = 0.25, `50%` = 0.25, `50%` = 0.25, `50%` = 0.3684, 
`50%` = 0.2857, `50%` = 0.1923, `50%` = 0.0263, `50%` = 0.0526, 
`50%` = 0.3026, `50%` = 0.2056, `50%` = 0.4079, `50%` = 0.3684, 
`50%` = 0.1316, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, 
`50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, 
`50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0.05, 
`50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, 
`50%` = 0, `50%` = 0, `50%` = 0.0526, `50%` = 0), q3 = c(`75%` = 0, 
`75%` = 0, `75%` = 0.1, `75%` = 0.0125, `75%` = 0.15, `75%` = 0.175, 
`75%` = 0.1, `75%` = 0.1818, `75%` = 0.1591, `75%` = 0.2295, 
`75%` = 0.2922, `75%` = 0.2273, `75%` = 0.5114, `75%` = 0.3929, 
`75%` = 0.15, `75%` = 0.35, `75%` = 0.3, `75%` = 0.25, `75%` = 0.45, 
`75%` = 0.35, `75%` = 0.2, `75%` = 0.0395, `75%` = 0.1289, `75%` = 0.55, 
`75%` = 0.375, `75%` = 0.575, `75%` = 0.4658, `75%` = 0.2329, 
`75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, 
`75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0.0109, `75%` = 0, 
`75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0.05, `75%` = 0, 
`75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, `75%` = 0, 
`75%` = 0, `75%` = 0.0882, `75%` = 0), group = c("high", "high", 
"high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", 
"high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", 
"high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", 
"high", "high", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", 
"low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", 
"low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", 
"low", "low")), row.names = c(NA, -55L), groups = structure(list(
    Zone = c("Crocodile", "Rankin", "West", "Whipray"), .rows = structure(list(
        c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
        34L, 35L), c(8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 36L, 37L, 
        38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L), c(15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
        20L, 21L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L), c(22L, 23L, 
        24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
        55L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the legend right when mixing different aesthetics and geoms is always a bit tricky. First, as your legend should display 5 different categories, simply mapping `group` on aesthetics isn't sufficient. Instead we have to crate two more categories for the colored lines and one for the black line. For the colored ones I use `paste0(group, "_line")` whereas for the black one I simply use `"2021"`. Second, to make sure that the legends for the different aesthetics, i.e. `color` and `fill` get merged I make sure that all five categories are displayed in each legend for which I use the `limits` argument. And of course do we need the same `labels` for each.  Moreover, we have to assign a value to each category. Finally, for the perfect look at to reflect the different linetypes and line widths in the legend too I also map on the `linetype` and the `linewidth` aesthetic.

```
library(ggplot2)

limits <- c("high", "high_line", "2021", "low", "low_line")
labels <- c(
  high = "25th - 75th percentile (High years)",
  low = "25th - 75th percentile (Low years)",
  high_line = "Median (High years)",
  low_line = "Median (Low years)",
  "2021" = "2021"
)

ggplot(ribbons, aes(x = Month, fill = group)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = q1, ymax = q3), alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(
    aes(
      x = Month, y = q2,
      color = paste0(group, "_line"),
      linetype = paste0(group, "_line"),
      linewidth = paste0(group, "_line")
    )
  ) +
  geom_line(
    data = blackline, mapping = aes(
      x = Month, y = q2, color = "2021",
      linetype = "2021",
      linewidth = "2021"
    ),
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  facet_wrap(factor(Zone) ~ .,
    labeller = as_labeller(c(
      "West" = "West",
      "Whipray" = "Whipray",
      "Rankin" = "Rankin",
      "Crocodile" = "Crocodile Dragover*"
    )),
    scales = "free"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = c(0, 0),
    limits = c(0, 1),
    breaks = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    limits = limits,
    labels = labels,
    values = c(
      high = "#d8e4bc", low = "#e8bcbc",
      high_line = "transparent", low_line = "transparent", "2021" = "transparent"
    )
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    limits = limits,
    labels = labels,
    values = c(
      low_line = "#DC143C", high_line = "#556B2F",
      low = "transparent", high = "transparent", "2021" = "black"
    )
  ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    limits = limits,
    labels = labels,
    values = c(
      low_line = "dashed", high_line = "dashed",
      low = "blank", high = "blank", "2021" = "solid"
    )
  ) +
  scale_linewidth_manual(
    limits = limits,
    labels = labels,
    values = c(
      low_line = .4, high_line = .4,
      low = .1, high = .1, "2021" = .8
    )
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
    legend.justification = "top",
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 7)
  ) +
  labs(y = "Frequency of Occurence", color = NULL, fill = NULL, linetype = NULL, linewidth = NULL)
```

[image]